# Relationship between algebraic data types and the set of real numbers

Tags: computer-science

I'm reading a book about the programming language Scala (["Functional Programming in Scala" by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)). They introduce the concept of an [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) (ADT), which is a kind of data type used in functional programming languages, defined as being composed of other types. For example, a `Tree` ADT (representing [the equivalently named data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))) can be defined as made of two separate types: `Branch` and `Leaf`, where a `Branch` has one or more children, while a `Leaf` has none. Clearly, any `Tree` can be defined in this fashion.

Now, the authors note the following:

> We say that the data type is the *sum* or *union* of its data constructors, and each data constructor is the *product* of its arguments, hence the name *algebraic* data type.

This sentence has a footnote attached, which is the root of my question:

> The naming is not coincidental. There's a deep connection, beyond the scope of this book, between the "addition" and "multiplication" of types to form an ADT and addition and multiplication of numbers.

My question is, what are they referring to? What is this relationship? What is the field of mathematics that studies this relationship, and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Relevant: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/, but in Haskell

Comment: usually   ADT stands for "abstract data type"

Comment: @miracle173 I am aware, the authors make note of that too, hence the explicit definition above as well as in the text

Comment: I am no expert, but after reading the linked blog post, it appears the set of ADTs form a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring). This is also stated in the second footnote [here](https://pavpanchekha.com/blog/zippers/derivative.html)

Comment: @eepperly16 that must be it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type systems can be taken to have semantics given by certain [categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) ([categorical semantics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+semantics)), and in these semantics product types correspond to the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) $\times$ and sum types correspond to the [categorical coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) $\sqcup$.

The relationship between these things and the usual product and sum is that if the category is chosen to be the category $\text{FinSet}$ of finite sets, then the categorical product is the cartesian product and the categorical coproduct is the disjoint union. In paticular, writing $|X|$ for the cardinality of a finite set $X$, we have

$$|X \times Y| = |X| \times |Y|$$

and

$$|X \sqcup Y| = |X| + |Y|.$$

In the categorical semantics the recursive construction of algebraic data types such as `Tree` is formalized using the notion of an [initial algebra for an endofunctor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor).

Comment: Thanks- a commenter on my original question said it was a reference to semirings. Are semirings related to category theory or no?

Comment: @ubadub: in some categories, products distribute over coproducts (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category). This is true in particular whenever the category is cartesian closed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), which in terms of type theory corresponds to having function types. In any such category the collection of isomorphism classes of objects can be turned into a semiring with addition given by coproduct and multiplication given by product. If you apply this construction to $\text{FinSet}$ you get the semiring of natural numbers (including zero).

Comment: There is also a category whose objects are semirings and morphisms are semiring homomorphisms but that's unrelated to this story.